# How to send tcp packets over established connection with nping?

Tags: networking, tcp

I can use `nping --tcp-connect -c 1 192.168.2.100` to establish a TCP connection which is closed within a fraction of a second. How can I send a TCP packet with a custom payload over that connection? I haven't found anything about it in the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nping).

Comment: From that link, do a `ctrl+f` and then search for "PAYLOAD OPTIONS".... it's on the man page you provided. You can also search for `TCP` with the same method but it seems to be possible based on quick look over that man page link you provided. It has `--data <hex string>`, `--data-string <text>`, and `--data-length <len>` for example. Also note that `--ether-type` states "*The Ethertype is used to indicate which protocol is encapsulated in the payload*"

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT It's not possible to set a payload in TCP Connect mode (`Warning: Payload supplied in TCP Connect mode. Payload will be ignored.`). I could send a TCP packet with a custom payload by using the `--tcp` mode instead of `--tcp-connect` however that wouldn't establish a connection but just send the packet.

Comment: I see, it does allow you to send the payload over the TCP connection but that payload is ignored.... I wonder if you could try something like https://linux.die.net/man/8/packit and play with its payload options.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Probably this is not possible with nping. I'll take a look at packit.

Comment: I'm curious to hear what the final method was you chose for this task in the end when you get a chance and confirm a working solution.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT `netcat` gets the job done in my particular case. However, the packages can only be configured to a limited extent, so this is unfortunately not an ideal solution.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask what your ultimate goal is that you are trying to accomplish with this task if you were to find a solution that suffices? I've not got much repetition on sending payload data in TCP packets so I'm just curious what your ultimate goal is just to ensure there's not some other idea that may go off in my head like a light coming on.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Actually, it is not a real-world application. I'm just teaching myself some network technology.